# My array resizing code is throwing an exception on new Data[size_t]

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a custom storage type, with an underlying array. However, my EnsureCapacity() method is throwing an exception in new.

I have no explanation, nor idea of how. The new[] is only trying to allocate 136,000 bytes, and the computer has 16 GB of RAM. It's a fairly standard Windows 10 machine running Visual Studio C++, so nothing too strange should be going on. To the best of my knowledge, I haven't done anything that should affect any part of the new[] or delete[] operator.

I've closed and restarted Visual Studio, and restarted Windows, and the error still persists. I am, frankly, baffled and clueless.

My code:

```
void EnsureCapacity()
{
    if (count >= size)
    {
        // The array can start empty.
        size_t newSize = std::max(2, size * 2);
        // The exception is thrown here, in the new operator.
        // Proved by following the call stack, and by tracing.
        Data* newArray = new Data[newSize];
        // It never gets here, or below.
        // "values" is a simple Data* type, that is already allocated.
        memcpy(newArray, values, size);
        size = newSize;
        delete[] values;
        values = newArray;
    }
}
```

I am unsure about posting the code where the exception happens, as it is MS's, not mine.

Comment: What exception is it throwing? As far as I understand it, the possibilities are that the allocation is failing with `std::bad_alloc`, one of the `Data`'s constructor is throwing or you have undefined behavior.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a `std::vector<Data>` instead of a raw pointer and `new[]`? Also when asking for debugging help, post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: 1)Are you sure that exception is thrown by operator "new" can you write the exact exception type that you get? 2) What is the actual value of variable "size" when you call "new" maybe you have an error during its calculation and the "size" is too big? 3) Are you sure that new operator is not overloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
memcpy(newArray, values, size);
```

This is wrong. memcpy takes the number of bytes. Size is the number of items you have. You should use

```
memcpy(newArray, values, size * sizeof(*newArray));
```

Without it, your array gets corrupted after the first incomplete copy. From there you probably cause an unintended write (in other code) access to data pertainning to the heap, which has the next allocation fail.

If that doesn't fix it, please enlighten us on sizeof(Data). And add debug prints in this code.

Comment: Also `memcpy` is not suitable for use with non-trivial types (but we can't tell that from the OP)

Comment: The test code uses a trivial type. Also, you are correct about needing sizeof(); however, the error itself was that count was not properly incremented, and it was encountering an out-of-bounds error and calling it a new[] error, AFAICT.